# Return empty arraylist instead of null

Tags: java

I need to adjust this method to return an empty "" instead of `null`, because I am supposed to use a class to test it and am getting a `NullPointerException`. How do I change this to return "" instead of `null`?

```
/**
 * Return the specified number of mail items for a user or
 * null if there are none.
 * @param who The user requesting their next item.
 * @param howMany The number of mail items requested.
 * @return The user's specified number of next items.
 */
public ArrayList<MailItem> getNextMailItems(String who, int howMany)
{
    ArrayList<MailItem> itemsToReturn = new ArrayList<MailItem>();
    if(who != null)
    {
        who = formatName(who);
    }
    ArrayList<MailItem> mails = items.get((who));
    Iterator<MailItem> it = mails.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext() && howMany > 0)
    {
        MailItem item = it.next();
        it.remove();
        itemsToReturn.add(item);
        howMany--;
        return itemsToReturn;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: return new ArrayList<>(); Just to avoid NPE you want new empty list? Are you sure that is your business case?

Comment: What @Nambari said and I have an extra question. Does this method ever return a list of `MailItem`s which has more than 1 item inside?

Answer (score 8):

I would always return an empty list instead of null:

What about this - I think the return inside the while loop is a bug. And at the beginning of your method you are creating an empty list - so why not return it in every case.

```
public ArrayList<MailItem> getNextMailItems(String who, int howMany)
{
    ArrayList<MailItem> itemsToReturn = new ArrayList<MailItem>();
    if(who != null)
    {
        who = formatName(who);
    }
    ArrayList<MailItem> mails = items.get((who));
    Iterator<MailItem> it = mails.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext() && howMany > 0)
    {
        MailItem item = it.next();
        it.remove();
        itemsToReturn.add(item);
        howMany--;
    }
    return itemsToReturn;
}
```

Also if `ArrayList<MailItem> mails = items.get((who));` returns null the following line returns a Nullpointer - `Iterator<MailItem> it = mails.iterator();` - So you should check for null before getting the iterator.

Answer (score 4):

simply use the ArrayList constructor:

```
return new ArrayList<MailItem>();
```